# Import Obj-C file which imports auto-generated Swift header

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, enums, objective-c-swift-bridge

This is a partial duplicate of [Import a file in bridging-header which imports Swift header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434410/import-a-file-in-bridging-header-which-imports-swift-header) but I encounter the same issue as [Rich](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434410/import-a-file-in-bridging-header-which-imports-swift-header#comment68552579_36434913)

> But what about enums declared in Swift? :(

I am porting an Obj-C iPad app to the iPhone. However I am a Swift developer who would really rather not rewrite existing functionality; replacing the UI instead.

I created a new target for the iPhone version. In my bridging header I import an obj-c class that uses `#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"`. Since this file is autogenerated it doesn't exist when I build this new target. The [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434410/import-a-file-in-bridging-header-which-imports-swift-header) answer is to add a `@class` but the legacy code makes use of an enum which is now giving the error "Expected a type".

```
// File that I am currently importing
-(void)setSmileyType:(SmileyFace)type andDelegate:(id<NumberRatingDelegate>)delegate;
// This line now throws an error "Expected a type"

//File that was previously auto imported
@objc public enum SmileyFace: Int {
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@objc enum` in Swift is exposed as a C-enum in ProjectName-Swift.h .
(Using a macro `SWIFT_ENUM`.)

You can put something like this into your Objective-C header files which are using the Swift enum:

```
typedef enum SmileyFace: NSInteger SmileyFace;
```

(Same as the first part of the generated code with the macro `SWIFT_ENUM`.)

Comment: Thank you. My project still crashes at runtime with this change but I'm currently working under the assumption that it is unrelated. I will accept if I can get my project to start or if I find definitively that this answer is complete.

Comment: This works for me, but why is this needed? Many other answers just say `@objc` should be enough for `Int` Swift enumerations.